# find out device display parameters on android - picking up wrong layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have several layouts in my Android application. All layouts have a tag to identify them during runtime, using the following code:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);

if(relativeLayout.getTag() != null)
{
    Log.v("Layout", (String) relativeLayout.getTag());
}
```

The following layouts are provided: "layout", "layout-long-port-hdpi-finger-800x480", "layout-long-port-hdpi-finger-854x480", "layout-normal-port-hdpi-finger-v15", "layout-normal-port-mdpi-finger-480x320".

When I use the Galaxy SIII emulator then the layout layout-normal-port-hdpi-finger-v15 will be picket.

Now I have downloaded the [Galaxy S II](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-S2-Skin-for-handset-emulation) emulator skin from the Samsung website and to my knowledge it is has a screen dimension of 480x800. It however dies not pick up the layout-long-port-hdpi-finger-800x480 layout, but rather always the default from the "Layout" directory.

**Question:** How can you find out what display requirements a device or an emulator has, so that I can fabricate a correct layout definition? Is there a way to debug / log these requirements?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Android takes the size of the notification bar into account when choosing resources. The Galaxy S II display is slightly smaller than 800 high when the notification bar is factored in. To debug this I recommend adding a values folder of the same name (values-long-port-hdpi-finger-800x480). Add a bools.xml file to that folder and put this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <bool name="your_display_size_name">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Also add a bools.xml file to values folders corresponding to all other display sizes (or just one that covers everything beside the screen for which you want the Boolean to be true for) put this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <bool name="your_display_size_name">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then get it programmatically and put it in a log or use it how you'd like.

```
boolean yourVariableName = false;
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.your_display_size_name)) {
        yourVariableName = true;
}
```

I would bet the notification bar is what's causing you issues, if not, this should help you debug.